# Untick an access checkbox

Tags: checkbox, ms-access-2007

i've got 2 checkbox in an option group, "I practice" and "I would like to practice". thanks to the option group, if one checkbox is ticked, the other one is unticked.

but, what i also would like is to be able to untick a checkbox by clicking on it again... but I don't know how to do it.

if someone has an idea !

Answer (score 0):

Add a third checkbox: None of the above, or I don't practice

Comment: yeah, I already think about it, but the customer doesn't want ;)

Comment: A button that resets the checkboxes, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

As you only have 2 checkboxes then you can add this sub routine to each one respectively:

```
Private Sub Check1_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    If Not Frame0 = 0 Then Frame0 = 0

End Sub
```

This assumes the frame is called **Frame0** but can easily be amended.

I'm amazed there isn't default functionality for this.

Comment: @kakashi99 This code is tried and tested, if it works for you then please consider accepting this answer so that the question is closed and others are aware when reading of the solution.